# Button icons background size

Tags: android, button, background, icons, size

I am using buttons for users to make selections, sized at 50dip square. If I use a button with text on it I get a rounded square with a 'flash' to confirm when pressed, all as normal. But the text doesn't really describe the button function and I want to use an image. I have tried a 24x24 png as the background but the resolution on the emulator is awful, extremely pixelated and at a resolution that is nothing like the rounded corners of a 'normal', text only, button (trying to round the corners of the background image makes it look like a ziggurat). What is the best way to address this? Should I use a bmp of say 250pixels square and let android compress it, or are there better ways to get a satisfactory resolution bmp on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

**I assume** you want to set the button background which grows/shrink automatically (resolution independent graphics), if this is the case then there is one tool already there by Android: [**Draw 9-patch**](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) tool.

So create a 40*40 or 50*50 9-patch background image and then set it inside the button.

For more info about Draw 9-patch tool, just click on the above link.
And
Here is the best example i have found so far: http://www.dibbus.com/2011/03/9patch-images-in-android/

**Example of 9-patch graphics** (Taken from above example link):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this, hopefully a circle image will finally display well.

Comment: For the record, I solved it by making the icons slightly larger than the 50dip so android compressed them, a little. I suspect that for objects with dip dimensions the images should be >= to the object size otherwise android will expand them and this expansion might have produced the 'pixellation'.

Answer (score 0):

Android scales drawables according to screen resolution. So a fairly small drawable, defined in dips will perhaps look okay on low-resolution screens, but very ugly on high-resolution screens. You can however tell Android which drawables to use depending on the screen resolution.

Setup a folder-structure like this in your resources folder:

- drawable
- drawable-ldpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-hdpi

That way you can create resolution-specific graphics for your application. You keep the default "drawable" folder for cross-resolution graphics (XML defined drawables etc.). Hope this helps in the more general sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the Android developer guide. More specifically that part:

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I had read this but didn't see (or missed it?) anything that suggested what pixel icons related to 50 dps.

Comment: As a general rule, multiply your mdpi sizes by 1.5 to get hdpi size. For instance a 50px button mdpi should be provided in 75px size for hdpi in order not to look pixelated. You also need to learn how to use 9-patch images as suggested in another answer.